# why this list comprehension does not work

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-3.5

I am looking for someone who can tell me why this list comprehension does not work

```
new_cards = [p if usr_card in deck1
         else p if usr_card in deck2
         else 'Removed' for p in cards]
```

`cards` is a list of list like this >> `cards = [ [deck1], [deck2] ]`
and `user_cards` is an item that could exist in one of the decks, `deck1` or `deck2` if not I want make that item in that index 'Removed' String

but the problem is even if the `usr_card` exist in one of the deck it turns to 'Removed'

Comment: You're looping over `cards`, but you say `user_cards` is what has the items that could exist in either deck... If `cards` is as you describe, you're checking whether a `list` of `deck1` is in `deck1` or `deck2` (which it won't be), then the same for a `list` of `deck2`.

Comment: Looking at this again... I'm not entirely sure where `usr_card`, `deck1` or `deck2` are coming from. Could you post a more complete code example and lay out your goal in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting this to make it clear there are an inline `if` statement and collapsing the logic a bit:

```
new_cards = [
    (p
     if usr_card in deck1
     or usr_card in deck2
     else 'Removed')
    for p in cards
]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if usr_card in deck1 or usr_card in deck2:
    new_cards = [p for p in cards]
else:
    new_cards = ['Removed'] * len(cards)
```

I don't think that's what you want.

Maybe you're looking to iterate through each of the sub-decks as remove cards?

```
new_cards = [
    [(card if card in deck1+deck2 else 'Removed') for card in deck]
    for deck in cards
]
```

#### A general tip for creating list comprehensions

Unfortunately I'm not really sure what each of those variables represent or what the expected output is so I can't tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

But **[I recommend copy-pasting your way into a list comprehension](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)** when you're learning. That's the method I use when I'm having trouble figuring out how to write them.

Answer (score 0):

As written, your code returns:

- either [[deck1],[deck2]]
- or ['Removed', 'Removed']

Depending if usr_card is in cards or not.

That's because p iterate over elements of cards. cards has only two elements : deck1 and deck2.

It seems, but your requirements are not clear, that you want to deal with the concatenation of the to decks.

```
cards = deck1 + deck2
```

Moreover, Removed will never be printed as by definition, if usr_card is not in cards, that item can't be marked.

Please be more clear about what are your business rules.

Answer (score 0):

`new_cards = [p if p in usr_card else 'removed' for deck in cards for p in deck]` should do it, although may need a bit of tweaking depending what exactly is going on in your code, I'm not too clear.